# Tcp packets using QTcpSocket

Tags: qt, tcp

I know that TCP guarantees that all packets will arrive. But can a packet be separated into 2 or more? I am using Qt with class QTcpSocket, and I want to know is `ReadyRead()` signal is emitted only when full packet arrives. Or in other words, is there any sense to send packet size in first bytes and then wait in loop until all bytes had arrived? Or I can just call `socket->readAll()` and I must get one full packet?

Comment: TCP communications are stream-based. In user mode program you don't have access to physical packets. You need to implement stream parsing logic. For example, if sender sends 12 and 34, receiver may read them as 12 34 or 1234 or 1 2 3 4 or 123 4 etc. Your program must handle correctly all these situations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a large amount of data is sent, the packet can arrive in separate parts. Alternatively, multiple messages can be received in one readyRead slot.

It's good practice to control this by setting the first byte(s) to the number of bytes that will be sent. Then, in readyRead, you read the first bytes and append the data to a buffer until the expected amount of data has been received.

In receiving data, this also means that if multiple messages are received in one call to readyRead(), you can know where the first message ends and the next one begins.

Here's an example of a client that receives data in a readyRead function()

```
void MyClass::readyRead()
{
    // m_pConnection is a QTcpSocket

    while(m_pConnection->bytesAvailable())
    {
        QByteArray buffer;

        int dataSize;
        m_pConnection->read((char*)&dataSize, sizeof(int));
        buffer = m_pConnection->read(dataSize);

        while(buffer.size() < dataSize) // only part of the message has been received
        {
            m_pConnection->waitForReadyRead(); // alternatively, store the buffer and wait for the next readyRead()
            buffer.append(m_pConnection->read(dataSize - buffer.size())); // append the remaining bytes of the message
        }

        QString msg(buffer); // data in this case is JSON, so we can use a QString
        emit Log(QString("\tMessage Received: %1").arg(msg));

        // Do something with the message
        ProcessMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: just one byte may be a bit small (only 255 size) an int has much more room

Comment: @ratchetfreak, good point, though of-course it depends on what data is being sent

Comment: The waitForReadyRead function does not have the intended effect in this example.  The documentation on the function says if you call waitForReadyRead() inside a slot connected to readyRead signal, the signal will not be remitted even if it returns true.  http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#readyRead

Comment: @mastash3ff It works as intended and the documentation is correct. If called from within the `readyRead` slot, the `readyRead` slot will not be entered again when `waitForReadyRead` returns true. If it did enter the `readyRead` function again, when the data is available, this code wouldn't work as intended. [waitForReadyRead](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#waitForReadyRead) is a blocking function and does not require an event loop.

Comment: Is the waitForReadyRead suppose to pause like a sleep or immediately return then continue loop.  I got the ladder and did not expect that functionality.

Comment: It's a blocking function, so it will sit and wait for data to arrive and no more code will execute on this thread, until data is received. Depending on the design of your code, it may not be ideal if you do this on the main (Gui) thread and are using large sizes of packets; in which case you'd be better off storing the buffer in the class and returning from the function, building the buffer on successive calls to readyRead.

Comment: side note: this may fail when the receiving and sending devices have different [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)(Because it is dealing integer bytes as it is a char array). That's why it is better to use serialization formats such as [`QDataStream`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#details) or JSON.

Comment: @Mike - Good point, thanks for adding this. Alternatively you can use Qt's [conversion functions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtendian.html), if you know what systems you're using.

Comment: **The packet can be broken up arbitrarily *independently of the amount of data sent*.** There's nothing that implies that it will be broken up only when a "large" amount of data is sent. You can send two bytes and receive them one at a time.

Comment: @KubaOber, fair point, though it's not something I've ever witnessed myself with small data packets - "large" is relative!