# How to use QTcpSocket for high frequent sending of small data packages?

Tags: qt, sockets, tcp, qtcpsocket

We have two Qt applications. App1 accepts a connection from App2 through `QTcpServer` and stores it in an instance of `QTcpSocket* tcpSocket`. App1 runs a simulation with 30 Hz. For each simulation run, a `QByteArray` consisting of a few kilobytes is sent using the following code (from the main/GUI thread):

```
    QByteArray block;
    /* lines omitted which write data into block */
    tcpSocket->write(block, block.size());
    tcpSocket->waitForBytesWritten(1);
```

The receiver socket listens to the QTcpSocket::readDataBlock signal (in main/GUI thread) and prints the corresponding time stamp to the GUI.

When both App1 and App2 run on the same system, the packages are perfectly in sync. However when App1 and App2 are run on different systems connected through a network, App2 is no longer in sync with the simulation in App2. The packages come in much slower. Even more surprising (and indicating our implementation is wrong) is the fact that when we stop the simulation loop, no more packages are received. This surprises us, because we expect from the TCP protocol that all packages will arrive eventually.

We built the TCP logic based on Qt's [fortune example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-fortuneserver.html). The fortune server, however, is different, because it only sends one package per incoming client. Could someone identify what we have done wrong?

Note: we use MSVC2012 (App1), MSVC2010 (App2) and Qt 5.2.

**Edit:** With a package I mean the result of a single simulation experiment, which is a bunch of numbers, written into `QByteArray block`. The first bits, however, contain the length of the QByteArray, so that the client can check whether all data has been received. This is the code which is called when the signal QTcpSocket::readDataBlock is emitted:

```
    QDataStream in(tcpSocket);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_2);

    if (blockSize == 0) {
      if (tcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < (int)sizeof(quint16))
         return; // cannot yet read size from data block

      in >> blockSize; // read data size for data block
    }

    // if the whole data block is not yet received, ignore it
    if (tcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < blockSize)
      return;

    // if we get here, the whole object is available to parse
    QByteArray object;
    in >> object;

    blockSize = 0; // reset blockSize for handling the next package

    return;
```

Comment: TCP doesn't have packages/packets - it's just a byte stream. How have you sliced up the data ? i.e. how do your receiving application know when 1 of your own data "packets" begin and another end ? Also, TCP has flow control, so if you stop reading data, buffers in the TCP stack fill up, and no more data will be sent (and the sender will block when trying to send unless your sockets are in non-blocking mode). It is however very hard to guess what you do wrong when we don't know what you do, or how you simulation work or how it somehow becomes "out of sync"

Comment: I tried to answer your question by editing my original question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: it seems you risk reading more data than what you want, if e.g. your blocksize is 1024 but  `tcpSocket->bytesAvailable()` happens to have 1222 bytes available, you read the start of the next block too, by the looks of it - so you'd probably have to use `in.readBytes()` instead, where you can specify how much to read. (And verify afterwards that it actually read that much data). However that does also depend on how your protocol is. If e.g. it's a simple request/reply, where your sender *never* sends any data until it has received a reply for the previous packet, current code seems ok

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tcp packets using QTcpSocket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909682/tcp-packets-using-qtcpsocket)

Comment: @nos: I checked and you are indeed right, `tcpSocket->bytesAvailable()` happens to be > `blockSize`.
@Merlin069: the question is not really a duplicate, the answer is more or less. I cannot apply the answer to my case, where we use `QDataStream`s which I cannot be parsed and appended like `QByteArray`s. I have to use `QDataStream`, because App1 and App2 are on different platforms. I tried `in.device()->seek()` for reparsing in the wait-loop from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909682/tcp-packets-using-qtcpsocket, however this is not allowed because the device is not random-access.

Comment: @nos: we don't have a request/reply protocol. The simulation will always send in 30 Hz time intervals. App2 will have to deal with data piling up. It is able to detect latency by evaluating the timestamp of each package.

Comment: Right, then you easily run into the situation I described where you read too much data, and you should try to use in.readBytes() in some way instead of `in >> object;`

Comment: @nos Thank you. It is now working as expected. Are you okay with me adding the working code as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in our implementation was caused by data packages being piled up and incorrect handling of packages which had only arrived partially.

The answer goes in the direction of [Tcp packets using QTcpSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909682/tcp-packets-using-qtcpsocket). However this answer could not be applied in a straightforward manner, because we rely on `QDataStream` instead of plain `QByteArray`.

The following code (run each time `QTcpSocket::readDataBlock` is emitted) works for us and shows how a raw series of bytes can be read from `QDataStream`. Unfortunately it seems that it is not possible to process the data in a clearer way (using `operator>>`).

```
    QDataStream in(tcpSocket);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_2);

    while (tcpSocket->bytesAvailable())
    {
        if (tcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < (int)(sizeof(quint16) + sizeof(quint8)+ sizeof(quint32)))
            return; // cannot yet read size and type info from data block

        in >> blockSize;
        in >> dataType; 

        char* temp = new char[4]; // read and ignore quint32 value for serialization of QByteArray in QDataStream       
        int bufferSize = in.readRawData(temp, 4);
        delete temp;
        temp  = NULL;

        QByteArray buffer;

        int objectSize = blockSize - (sizeof(quint16) + sizeof(quint8)+ sizeof(quint32));

        temp = new char[objectSize];            
        bufferSize = in.readRawData(temp, objectSize);
        buffer.append(temp, bufferSize);
        delete temp;
        temp  = NULL;

        if (buffer.size() == objectSize)
        {
            //ready for parsing             
        }
        else if (buffer.size() > objectSize)
        {
            //buffer size larger than expected object size, but still ready for parsing
        }
        else
        {
            // buffer size smaller than expected object size
            while (buffer.size() < objectSize) 
            {               
                tcpSocket->waitForReadyRead();
                char* temp = new char[objectSize - buffer.size()];          
                int bufferSize = in.readRawData(temp, objectSize - buffer.size());
                buffer.append(temp, bufferSize);
                delete temp;
                temp  = NULL;
            }
            // now ready for parsing
        }
        if (dataType == 0) 
        {               
            // deserialize object               
        }

    }
```

Please not that the first three bytes of the expected `QDataStream` are part of our own procotol: `blockSize` indicates the number of bytes for a complete single package, `dataType` helps deserializing the binary chunk.

**Edit**
For reducing the latency of sending objects through the TCP connection, disabling packet bunching was very usefull:

```
    // disable Nagle's algorithm to avoid delay and bunching of small packages
    tcpSocketPosData->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::LowDelayOption,1);
```