# Qt QTcpSocket readAll fuction not reading whole data from socket

Tags: qt, qtnetwork

I got super simple code.

```
QTcpSocket* sock = new QTcpSocket();
connect(sock - readyread) and other signals
sock->connectToHost();
sock->write();

//readyread
qDebug() << "available" <<  sock->bytesAvailable();
QByteArray a = sock->readAll
qDebug() << "readed"  << a.size()
```

and as output i got:

available - 4677
readed - 681

available - 8760
readed - 114

available - 10899
readed - 59

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tcp packets using QTcpSocket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909682/tcp-packets-using-qtcpsocket)

Comment: @TheDarkKnight as a fully working solution already used simple read(socket->bytesAvailable) and that works! but your link also useful.

Comment: bytesAvailable returns an int, not your data.  Are you sure you're not just reading garbage?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with multiple connect to ReadyRead signal in my concrete realization of networking.
(in parent and in child class)
My bad