# Server crashes when it receives a request while it is already processing a request

Tags: c++, qt, networking, asynchronous

The server code I have works fine as long as only one request is being sent at a time. The data flows like this: The client does something, like click a button, and data is sent to the server. A header of type `uint16_t` is prepended to this data so that the server knows how many bytes out of the bytes available to read for this one request - a solution I thought would fix the problem I'm having. On the server, I connect the `readyRead` signal from `QTcpSocket` to a function that reads the header like this:

```
void Server::getHeader(){    
    QTcpSocket *client = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket *>(sender());
        if (!client)
            return;

    forever {
        int N = sizeof(uint16_t);
        qint64 bytes = client->bytesAvailable();
        if (bytes < N) break;
        QByteArray buf = client->read(N);
        emit hasData(buf, client); //contains the number of bytes in the stream for this request and a reference to the current client
    }
}
```

The `hasData` signal will trigger a function that will do the same thing the `getHeader` function does, but will wait for `bytes` number of bytes to be available instead of `sizeof(uint16_t)` bytes to be available. Once it sees that the desired number of bytes are available, it reads that many bytes from the stream and stores them in a `char[]`, then sends it to a function which makes sense of the data (where the problem occurs) like this:

```
void Server::handleConnection(std::string serverReceiveBuf, QTcpSocket *client){
    receivedData data; //a struct that organizes the data to be easily readable by a human
    QString stringBuilder;
    try{
        data.activityID = serverReceiveBuf.at(0);
        data.stringCount = serverReceiveBuf.at(1);
        int i,
            j = 2, //placeholder for next slot to be used in the receive buffer
            k = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < data.stringCount; i++){ //while there are strings whose lengths we need to document
            data.stringLength.insert(i, serverReceiveBuf.at(2+i));
            j++;
        }
        while(k < data.stringCount){ //while there are strings in the buffer to be put into the data structure
            i = 0;
            while(i < data.stringLength.at(k)){ //while there are characters in the buffer to be built into a string
                stringBuilder.append(serverReceiveBuf.at(j));
                j++;
                i++;
            }
            //we have assembled a string from chars in the buffer
            //now we put them into the struct
            data.stringData << stringBuilder;
            stringBuilder = ""; //empty string builder for next string.
            k++;
        }
    }
    catch(std::exception e){
        qDebug() << "[" << currentTime() << "] " << "An undefined buffer error occurred.";
    }

    //Handle based on activity ID
}
```

I put this code into a try/catch to prevent the server from crashing. It's not meant to be descriptive right now. If I take it out, the server will crash as soon as I try to access data that should be in `serverReceiveBuf` - the string of characters read from the stream of available bytes - because it's empty. With the try/catch block, any requests sent while one was still processing are just ignored and the error message is display on the server console.

Now here's the frustrating part: When I try to step through the code with the debugger, it works. Presumably because the request is finished processing by the time the debugger goes back to handle the second request. I thought the requests were supposed to be queued up, but apparently not. Is there something special I have to do to force queuing of data so that I can ensure that the current request is processed before trying to handle the next one?

Comment: Do you have a backtrace of the crash/exception (try setting a catchpoint on throw)? You could also print e.what() to learn more about the exception. You make assumptions about the length of `serverReceiveBuf` without checking. Are you sure it has the expected length? And no, unless you use explicit multithreading or return to the event loop, no further data will be processed while you're processing one chunk.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I checked `serverReceiveBuf` and found that the crashes were caused by an empty `serverReceiveBuf` being passed to `handleConnection`. I didn't think this would be possible but as a temporary fix I modified the server a bit so that it can continue running by ignoring these empty `serverReceiveBuf`s, though this makes the server run much slower and causes a lot of requests to be ignored, even ones that shouldn't be sending empty `serverReceiveBuf`s. I'm probably going to try to pin this problem down and start over since the code is a mess and i'm just doing this to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
forever 
{
        int N = sizeof(uint16_t);
        qint64 bytes = client->bytesAvailable();
        if (bytes < N) break;
        QByteArray buf = client->read(N);
        emit hasData(buf, client); //contains the number of bytes in the stream for this request and a reference to the current client
}
```

Qt is event driven and relies on events to handle the signals, such as your emit hasData call.

Assuming your server receives data greater than the size of uint16_t (which is very likely), the server will get stuck in your forever loop and not be able to process its own events, such as handling your call to emit hasData.

You can test this by adding a call to QApplication::processEvents() at the bottom of the loop to ensure that the Qt events are processed. Ideally, you should not use that function, but refactor your code so that it gracefully returns from the function, until more data is received for processing.

Comment: Doesn't emitting that signal cause the slot it's connected to to begin executing? If it was stuck in that forever loop I wouldn't expect it to crash in a function that can only execute after that signal was emitted, right? Because it isn't hanging in that loop.

Comment: That's a fair question. It depends upon the type of connection between the signal and its slot which is made in the connect call. Even if it's direct and the function is called, you should never sit in a forever loop when an event loop is present and needs processing. Since both functions are part of the Server class, why are you even using a signal here and not calling the function directly?

Comment: Also note that since the readyRead signal is connected to getHeader, which implements a forever loop, it will never return to the message handler to notify you that more data is ready to read. Perhaps the answer here may help you understand how to use readyRead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909682/tcp-packets-using-qtcpsocket/26909955#26909955

Comment: I've been working on this for a few months and I was a considerably worse programmer when I started this, and `getHeader` was one of the first things I wrote in the project. I'm likely going to start over once I understand Qt better since the entire project is such a mess. Anyway that readyRead function is the slot connected to the readyRead signal in `QTcpSoket`? The reason I didn't implement it like that from the beginning is because I was worried the entire message might not have arrived yet, but there would be no `bytesAvailable` because of latency.

Comment: I just realized how you prevented that from happening. I'll try an implementation like this and see how it goes.

Comment: I appreciate your help. The solution you provided in the comments works wonderfully with a couple of slight modifications. I was able to have 100 concurrent users all sending lots of data to the server seamlessly (although it was slow, that's easily fixed since the current iteration of the code is single threaded)